# ¿es adecuado publicar 2 respuestas a la misma pregunta?

Tags: discusión

He visto [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11877/como-obtener-el-response-de-un-array-de-php-en-ajax/12930#12930) en la que un usuario, tras conversar con el preguntador ha posteado 2 respuestas.

La verdad es que no son iguales ya que una complementa a la otra.

**Es adecuado hacer esto?**

Si no, como se debe actuar?

- Reporto?
- Aviso al usuario?

Comment: Lo correcto sería (des de mi punto de vista), editar la primera respuesta y añadir lo que comenta. Quizá deberías reportar con aviso a moderador explicando la situación para que se fusionen esas 2 respuestas.

Comment: Estoy con @Miquel Coll, lo normal sería responder en una sola, y en caso de que pasase, avisar al usuario de como sería lo correcto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Respecto a lo correcto por parte del usuario, en efecto lo suyo sería ampliar la primera respuesta, no escribir una nueva.

*Lo siguiente es opinión personal mía, no política oficial de Stack Overflow:*

Respecto a qué hacer, en principio sería suficiente con escribir un comentario informando al usuario de cuál es el procedimiento correcto. Sólo si el usuario sigue haciendo lo mismo más veces podría ser conveniente la intervención de un moderador - pero sinceramente tampoco veo esto como una "falta grave".

Comment: Se debería añadir algún matiz sobre que esta respuesta es para el caso expuesto en particular. Hay casos en los que dos respuestas son recomendables.

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión el dilema es casuístico. Cada situación es diferente de las demás.

En este caso en particular, debe reportarse, porque ambas son **parte de la misma pregunta**, no es que sean diferentes y una complemente a la otra, es la misma respuesta dividida en dos, por eso debe reportarse.

> #### La evidencia es clara:
>
> La primera respuesta es clara y completa por si misma, además resuelve el problema en comento. **La segunda pregunta *no tiene sentido* sin la primera**.

Entonces, la segunda parte debería integrarse con la primera respuesta.

Atención, que esto aplica solo para este caso particular. Otras situaciones pueden ser diferentes, por lo tanto, **no se puede aplicar la misma política a todas las preguntas que tengan dos respuestas del mismo autor**.

Comment: ^ Esto. Si las respuestas son variaciones de lo mismo o depende la una de la otra, se debe editar. Si son dos maneras diferentes de obtener el mismo resultado, se puede publicar una nueva respuesta.